# My button not work on my page web CSS & HTML

Tags: php, html, css

Today I have tried change style my page web, I have added a new CSS
but the problem is I have to try adding a button link with href, but when I press the button it does not work.

If I press the button "Link Here" nothing is happening, I think it's a problem with the CSS.

I have tried all the methods I have found on google but nothing work, thanks for your help!

My page web:

```
<?php require '../global.php'; ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Page Web</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>body,
html {
    height: 100%
}

#stars,
#stars:after {
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    box-shadow: 845px 1368px #FFF, 1635px 163px #FFF, 659px 1285px #FFF, 709px 1347px #FFF, 1464px 1089px #FFF, 45px 1588px #FFF, 616px 409px #FFF, 1797px 1793px #FFF, 710px 1024px #FFF, 507px 880px #FFF, 345px 739px #FFF, 1012px 1615px #FFF, 1964px 869px #FFF, 585px 677px #FFF, 19px 1153px #FFF, 224px 55px #FFF, 1627px 1756px #FFF, 1745px 844px #FFF, 848px 1681px #FFF, 112px 1970px #FFF, 1709px 1577px #FFF, 1690px 1656px #FFF, 1558px 690px #FFF, 1655px 1772px #FFF, 1276px 1627px #FFF, 160px 100px #FFF, 1318px 117px #FFF, 1086px 1931px #FFF, 376px 1617px #FFF, 1471px 854px #FFF, 1157px 1569px #FFF, 1678px 561px #FFF, 989px 153px #FFF, 10px 854px #FFF, 1469px 87px #FFF, 24px 1865px #FFF, 1768px 1525px #FFF, 370px 1749px #FFF, 259px 1684px #FFF, 1754px 1530px #FFF, 424px 1309px #FFF, 1133px 16px #FFF, 1837px 9px #FFF, 1206px 1263px #FFF, 412px 517px #FFF, 926px 339px #FFF, 1065px 975px #FFF, 1472px 620px #FFF, 1134px 1825px #FFF, 1640px 585px #FFF, 116px 1426px #FFF, 1924px 1778px #FFF, 58px 430px #FFF, 186px 328px #FFF, 756px 502px #FFF, 382px 676px #FFF, 556px 203px #FFF, 871px 975px #FFF, 772px 1557px #FFF, 105px 63px #FFF, 1127px 1617px #FFF, 65px 633px #FFF, 228px 404px #FFF, 1184px 360px #FFF, 398px 1929px #FFF, 541px 1496px #FFF, 1508px 1511px #FFF, 791px 400px #FFF, 913px 33px #FFF, 7px 1662px #FFF, 490px 500px #FFF, 1531px 723px #FFF, 1498px 796px #FFF, 259px 1805px #FFF, 1331px 5px #FFF, 816px 1638px #FFF, 1945px 1770px #FFF, 1098px 1675px #FFF, 424px 1712px #FFF, 183px 1702px #FFF, 282px 145px #FFF, 1752px 359px #FFF, 1296px 1091px #FFF, 499px 1739px #FFF, 1562px 1769px #FFF, 1199px 948px #FFF, 228px 1578px #FFF, 286px 1846px #FFF, 517px 376px #FFF, 1242px 580px #FFF, 401px 1100px #FFF, 1244px 503px #FFF, 1470px 944px #FFF, 1625px 1884px #FFF, 1446px 20px #FFF, 545px 1472px #FFF, 479px 1533px #FFF, 735px 278px #FFF, 1513px 498px #FFF, 1409px 1617px #FFF, 266px 1034px #FFF, 1634px 641px #FFF, 603px 1873px #FFF, 1956px 1000px #FFF, 1689px 1787px #FFF, 303px 250px #FFF, 281px 646px #FFF, 1349px 1713px #FFF, 541px 1194px #FFF, 457px 493px #FFF, 801px 1751px #FFF, 1788px 1090px #FFF, 866px 942px #FFF, 660px 847px #FFF, 1643px 535px #FFF, 1250px 817px #FFF, 834px 1606px #FFF, 959px 1763px #FFF, 1950px 114px #FFF, 994px 1899px #FFF, 759px 958px #FFF, 1442px 1963px #FFF, 1332px 1876px #FFF, 446px 1706px #FFF, 731px 1691px #FFF, 1890px 921px #FFF, 616px 1315px #FFF, 142px 1448px #FFF, 1175px 1375px #FFF, 138px 718px #FFF, 1793px 1194px #FFF, 1761px 816px #FFF, 1268px 302px #FFF, 877px 111px #FFF, 585px 744px #FFF, 1548px 1727px #FFF, 722px 1415px #FFF, 1138px 926px #FFF, 826px 372px #FFF, 1071px 878px #FFF, 1772px 1634px #FFF, 1190px 1272px #FFF, 1034px 663px #FFF, 1408px 1570px #FFF, 1356px 1056px #FFF, 822px 1280px #FFF, 1301px 1371px #FFF, 1752px 1476px #FFF, 1296px 1719px #FFF, 1633px 186px #FFF, 1649px 1600px #FFF, 83px 470px #FFF, 1187px 533px #FFF, 1473px 747px #FFF, 787px 584px #FFF, 1947px 496px #FFF, 179px 269px #FFF, 895px 308px #FFF, 912px 1264px #FFF, 1555px 1574px #FFF, 1038px 563px #FFF, 1898px 1688px #FFF, 1259px 191px #FFF, 187px 1753px #FFF, 217px 447px #FFF, 766px 66px #FFF, 71px 684px #FFF, 133px 657px #FFF, 603px 287px #FFF, 1324px 730px #FFF, 929px 581px #FFF, 563px 1460px #FFF, 624px 814px #FFF, 951px 1225px #FFF, 334px 1818px #FFF, 1274px 1934px #FFF, 1446px 1147px #FFF, 179px 1258px #FFF, 1097px 1479px #FFF, 1629px 1107px #FFF, 1193px 1104px #FFF, 47px 690px #FFF, 969px 1340px #FFF, 801px 1547px #FFF, 22px 1837px #FFF, 1552px 781px #FFF, 861px 1918px #FFF, 663px 1507px #FFF, 754px 1799px #FFF, 523px 1217px #FFF, 1538px 147px #FFF, 1104px 283px #FFF, 1405px 1403px #FFF, 1330px 1054px #FFF, 393px 275px #FFF, 46px 545px #FFF, 1688px 1919px #FFF, 815px 1232px #FFF, 266px 557px #FFF, 1818px 1093px #FFF, 1853px 1167px #FFF, 1603px 1747px #FFF, 470px 366px #FFF, 346px 1931px #FFF, 1281px 819px #FFF, 673px 1762px #FFF, 1212px 1380px #FFF, 219px 199px #FFF, 987px 794px #FFF, 467px 541px #FFF, 1192px 1975px #FFF, 931px 1909px #FFF, 1739px 595px #FFF, 1225px 471px #FFF, 623px 1898px #FFF, 1373px 1616px #FFF, 689px 839px #FFF, 1526px 370px #FFF, 1865px 750px #FFF, 371px 109px #FFF, 296px 813px #FFF, 106px 496px #FFF, 204px 1887px #FFF, 1643px 82px #FFF, 1773px 1069px #FFF, 912px 463px #FFF, 775px 1630px #FFF, 991px 466px #FFF, 175px 1173px #FFF, 1243px 1678px #FFF, 1978px 175px #FFF, 114px 1015px #FFF, 1724px 836px #FFF, 1714px 883px #FFF, 1216px 884px #FFF, 904px 1228px #FFF, 1721px 1317px #FFF, 1019px 1038px #FFF, 1017px 14px #FFF, 1428px 12px #FFF, 1818px 1079px #FFF, 1034px 447px #FFF, 1765px 360px #FFF, 1497px 1462px #FFF, 1857px 772px #FFF, 819px 75px #FFF, 1805px 1988px #FFF, 1482px 1432px #FFF, 1330px 1411px #FFF, 11px 1147px #FFF, 148px 54px #FFF, 858px 1756px #FFF, 208px 38px #FFF, 431px 369px #FFF, 1719px 460px #FFF, 1052px 217px #FFF, 1013px 1528px #FFF, 692px 715px #FFF, 1919px 619px #FFF, 1451px 1434px #FFF, 344px 564px #FFF, 34px 1665px #FFF, 41px 1659px #FFF, 377px 1253px #FFF, 1650px 337px #FFF, 875px 1960px #FFF, 1511px 661px #FFF, 1916px 798px #FFF, 42px 620px #FFF, 691px 401px #FFF, 1677px 1556px #FFF, 66px 1645px #FFF, 651px 1467px #FFF, 902px 1993px #FFF, 1339px 1049px #FFF, 1177px 229px #FFF, 1484px 336px #FFF, 1467px 1694px #FFF, 1549px 1754px #FFF, 1857px 449px #FFF, 539px 364px #FFF, 1257px 1668px #FFF, 884px 1040px #FFF, 1229px 785px #FFF, 906px 947px #FFF, 1778px 1185px #FFF, 1966px 1670px #FFF, 1322px 434px #FFF, 778px 246px #FFF, 1089px 1614px #FFF, 1833px 539px #FFF, 1473px 1098px #FFF, 1775px 279px #FFF, 705px 1040px #FFF, 1119px 233px #FFF, 1758px 1472px #FFF, 1775px 1924px #FFF, 1116px 1382px #FFF, 332px 730px #FFF, 1469px 174px #FFF, 1564px 284px #FFF, 1485px 1130px #FFF, 1595px 1145px #FFF, 1022px 246px #FFF, 477px 652px #FFF, 359px 196px #FFF, 1889px 1620px #FFF, 707px 1914px #FFF, 1336px 38px #FFF, 651px 39px #FFF, 226px 1310px #FFF, 391px 1831px #FFF, 414px 730px #FFF, 1642px 1492px #FFF, 815px 1131px #FFF, 222px 1858px #FFF, 1298px 1864px #FFF, 1568px 1627px #FFF, 879px 526px #FFF, 95px 1350px #FFF, 932px 822px #FFF, 898px 1250px #FFF, 1564px 1058px #FFF, 200px 1585px #FFF, 1448px 307px #FFF, 1164px 1694px #FFF, 1030px 1425px #FFF, 93px 692px #FFF, 658px 1114px #FFF, 861px 500px #FFF, 107px 77px #FFF, 1305px 572px #FFF, 975px 499px #FFF, 1940px 221px #FFF, 87px 1314px #FFF, 1228px 708px #FFF, 881px 2000px #FFF, 1566px 484px #FFF, 665px 1488px #FFF, 741px 1338px #FFF, 1788px 1582px #FFF, 890px 1872px #FFF, 1248px 869px #FFF, 480px 1158px #FFF, 455px 1652px #FFF, 773px 17px #FFF, 1329px 1973px #FFF, 967px 281px #FFF, 1261px 71px #FFF, 207px 1399px #FFF, 1938px 1634px #FFF, 1454px 995px #FFF, 941px 1499px #FFF, 1216px 303px #FFF, 1329px 1119px #FFF, 60px 1238px #FFF, 708px 738px #FFF, 632px 1345px #FFF, 126px 1330px #FFF, 1417px 1006px #FFF, 497px 842px #FFF, 1517px 106px #FFF, 861px 1625px #FFF, 572px 1044px #FFF, 290px 182px #FFF, 837px 170px #FFF, 606px 1617px #FFF, 711px 1044px #FFF, 991px 1421px #FFF, 1744px 75px #FFF, 255px 789px #FFF, 1025px 685px #FFF, 963px 1546px #FFF, 402px 762px #FFF, 331px 1336px #FFF, 1465px 206px #FFF, 400px 1133px #FFF, 105px 1268px #FFF, 675px 1190px #FFF, 952px 1702px #FFF, 11px 801px #FFF, 1359px 1237px #FFF, 1951px 1282px #FFF, 269px 1728px #FFF, 275px 361px #FFF, 1450px 1717px #FFF, 676px 1853px #FFF, 422px 1776px #FFF, 1728px 1790px #FFF, 712px 224px #FFF, 1288px 84px #FFF, 1030px 289px #FFF, 1108px 859px #FFF, 1036px 141px #FFF, 1571px 1059px #FFF, 1761px 902px #FFF, 1937px 612px #FFF, 1256px 610px #FFF, 1433px 1955px #FFF, 1965px 1760px #FFF, 1972px 1972px #FFF, 206px 288px #FFF, 1235px 1955px #FFF, 1273px 118px #FFF, 1900px 1028px #FFF, 566px 458px #FFF, 269px 405px #FFF, 369px 40px #FFF, 350px 524px #FFF, 1546px 1340px #FFF, 1468px 1377px #FFF, 473px 969px #FFF, 1132px 274px #FFF, 1835px 1582px #FFF, 1471px 634px #FFF, 433px 1093px #FFF, 966px 341px #FFF, 511px 965px #FFF, 1981px 672px #FFF, 587px 874px #FFF, 292px 1571px #FFF, 966px 1771px #FFF, 1427px 1327px #FFF, 1838px 1343px #FFF, 924px 1861px #FFF, 740px 631px #FFF, 842px 912px #FFF, 976px 619px #FFF, 572px 465px #FFF, 244px 102px #FFF, 781px 1261px #FFF, 1557px 1623px #FFF, 1148px 1018px #FFF, 1771px 287px #FFF, 483px 66px #FFF, 1763px 46px #FFF, 1874px 786px #FFF, 277px 496px #FFF, 1829px 1419px #FFF, 1677px 61px #FFF, 282px 1945px #FFF, 1532px 1803px #FFF, 1635px 747px #FFF, 1629px 24px #FFF, 1464px 57px #FFF, 1335px 664px #FFF, 1187px 1743px #FFF, 1488px 88px #FFF, 1471px 462px #FFF, 760px 593px #FFF, 1640px 1728px #FFF, 1819px 1950px #FFF, 1634px 452px #FFF, 847px 138px #FFF, 1428px 508px #FFF, 1934px 794px #FFF, 33px 285px #FFF, 1086px 120px #FFF, 1800px 1588px #FFF, 1516px 708px #FFF, 1988px 1520px #FFF, 1297px 1417px #FFF, 952px 1100px #FFF, 1322px 915px #FFF, 300px 1443px #FFF, 1975px 189px #FFF, 318px 1296px #FFF, 815px 282px #FFF, 1425px 1755px #FFF, 1020px 748px #FFF, 1731px 1634px #FFF, 164px 1539px #FFF, 1795px 475px #FFF, 812px 291px #FFF, 1977px 1454px #FFF, 1459px 490px #FFF, 68px 702px #FFF, 1828px 1146px #FFF, 566px 1508px #FFF, 1172px 387px #FFF, 469px 1001px #FFF, 1341px 1219px #FFF, 591px 1771px #FFF, 1488px 393px #FFF, 1595px 32px #FFF, 1916px 1107px #FFF, 1505px 1048px #FFF, 1515px 1223px #FFF, 1933px 1570px #FFF, 55px 1888px #FFF, 38px 1400px #FFF, 1301px 1455px #FFF, 538px 112px #FFF, 1613px 1274px #FFF, 1784px 1056px #FFF, 778px 626px #FFF, 560px 1902px #FFF, 597px 1999px #FFF, 981px 1774px #FFF, 1287px 1128px #FFF, 160px 84px #FFF, 18px 686px #FFF, 1583px 926px #FFF, 1795px 1640px #FFF, 1171px 828px #FFF, 586px 1382px #FFF, 3px 1779px #FFF, 1428px 889px #FFF, 433px 128px #FFF, 1849px 139px #FFF, 1834px 1985px #FFF, 1856px 1966px #FFF, 1846px 985px #FFF, 421px 170px #FFF, 541px 705px #FFF, 58px 1997px #FFF, 1867px 1690px #FFF, 940px 1936px #FFF, 1203px 447px #FFF, 78px 718px #FFF, 887px 1324px #FFF, 42px 1856px #FFF, 94px 1321px #FFF, 312px 1476px #FFF, 1925px 1541px #FFF, 1324px 1924px #FFF, 590px 1184px #FFF, 242px 884px #FFF, 1385px 1899px #FFF, 643px 1203px #FFF, 19px 1986px #FFF, 1660px 1650px #FFF, 562px 99px #FFF, 1045px 124px #FFF, 1939px 181px #FFF, 1181px 333px #FFF, 1616px 415px #FFF, 617px 777px #FFF, 1505px 443px #FFF, 1828px 1768px #FFF, 197px 1735px #FFF, 846px 352px #FFF, 1522px 1102px #FFF, 1364px 130px #FFF, 998px 286px #FFF, 72px 936px #FFF, 272px 656px #FFF, 213px 998px #FFF, 243px 323px #FFF, 87px 1448px #FFF, 1503px 740px #FFF, 1202px 896px #FFF, 723px 1273px #FFF, 1110px 1482px #FFF, 925px 1165px #FFF, 471px 1782px #FFF, 1227px 1363px #FFF, 264px 155px #FFF, 1056px 1326px #FFF, 1134px 565px #FFF, 58px 1529px #FFF, 99px 439px #FFF, 996px 70px #FFF, 79px 1867px #FFF, 989px 540px #FFF, 1px 1193px #FFF, 1329px 358px #FFF, 1867px 982px #FFF, 253px 1745px #FFF, 1796px 693px #FFF, 247px 367px #FFF, 217px 1683px #FFF, 602px 197px #FFF, 1826px 1164px #FFF, 270px 624px #FFF, 657px 1194px #FFF, 1508px 432px #FFF, 1846px 451px #FFF, 1343px 719px #FFF, 132px 253px #FFF, 514px 365px #FFF, 1973px 1617px #FFF, 1941px 251px #FFF, 271px 1779px #FFF, 1771px 1595px #FFF, 47px 863px #FFF, 908px 146px #FFF, 1676px 262px #FFF, 1809px 1472px #FFF, 836px 848px #FFF, 1522px 339px #FFF, 1155px 485px #FFF, 1286px 1224px #FFF, 1458px 812px #FFF, 930px 302px #FFF, 1861px 432px #FFF, 462px 1779px #FFF, 619px 353px #FFF, 1016px 290px #FFF, 1205px 1909px #FFF, 81px 1605px #FFF, 1874px 737px #FFF, 437px 592px #FFF, 182px 1105px #FFF, 557px 95px #FFF, 224px 1541px #FFF, 113px 1744px #FFF, 110px 345px #FFF, 310px 184px #FFF, 1748px 55px #FFF, 1695px 1364px #FFF, 91px 1621px #FFF, 1366px 1198px #FFF, 1661px 1371px #FFF, 93px 281px #FFF, 1973px 596px #FFF, 545px 770px #FFF, 1724px 701px #FFF, 1768px 1311px #FFF, 1425px 890px #FFF, 231px 252px #FFF, 1159px 1585px #FFF, 524px 185px #FFF, 576px 1589px #FFF, 954px 115px #FFF, 759px 283px #FFF, 322px 534px #FFF, 855px 896px #FFF, 653px 488px #FFF, 277px 1684px #FFF, 1195px 778px #FFF, 1239px 286px #FFF, 606px 1956px #FFF, 210px 949px #FFF, 107px 675px #FFF, 1347px 147px #FFF, 136px 1425px #FFF, 1484px 1389px #FFF, 1207px 524px #FFF, 549px 1700px #FFF, 1135px 678px #FFF, 279px 1924px #FFF, 911px 99px #FFF, 803px 389px #FFF, 1212px 1752px #FFF, 474px 1457px #FFF, 362px 964px #FFF, 342px 1949px #FFF, 542px 1602px #FFF, 419px 923px #FFF, 1701px 923px #FFF, 1101px 650px #FFF, 17px 85px #FFF, 931px 1420px #FFF, 1038px 351px #FFF, 1390px 448px #FFF, 140px 537px #FFF, 1551px 365px #FFF, 797px 1946px #FFF, 1262px 78px #FFF, 403px 1371px #FFF, 548px 232px #FFF, 1250px 132px #FFF, 1826px 464px #FFF, 1854px 1861px #FFF, 792px 1501px #FFF, 469px 1479px #FFF, 264px 1186px #FFF, 952px 61px #FFF, 925px 802px #FFF, 20px 1579px #FFF, 823px 1712px #FFF, 4px 260px #FFF, 199px 437px #FFF, 435px 463px #FFF, 1948px 1621px #FFF, 1592px 867px #FFF, 1625px 1795px #FFF, 1858px 146px #FFF, 1825px 172px #FFF, 610px 1138px #FFF, 167px 811px #FFF, 93px 1833px #FFF, 1418px 1160px #FFF, 932px 1201px #FFF, 904px 275px #FFF, 1801px 775px #FFF, 676px 502px #FFF, 1207px 1708px #FFF, 1432px 475px #FFF, 531px 1518px #FFF, 1477px 696px #FFF, 1498px 1209px #FFF, 1503px 391px #FFF, 547px 1939px #FFF, 1095px 1690px #FFF, 1741px 1365px #FFF, 1556px 1880px #FFF, 612px 1771px #FFF, 576px 154px #FFF
}

#stars2,
#stars2:after {
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    box-shadow: 525px 701px #FFF, 998px 1574px #FFF, 1525px 1926px #FFF, 1511px 1992px #FFF, 1124px 582px #FFF, 273px 1978px #FFF, 1228px 235px #FFF, 1253px 1486px #FFF, 573px 1682px #FFF, 1004px 658px #FFF, 221px 1545px #FFF, 1700px 1181px #FFF, 1707px 893px #FFF, 150px 1154px #FFF, 1822px 1200px #FFF, 177px 1280px #FFF, 1258px 1128px #FFF, 503px 1507px #FFF, 1629px 123px #FFF, 518px 156px #FFF, 1326px 800px #FFF, 1006px 508px #FFF, 872px 1294px #FFF, 1807px 918px #FFF, 482px 1294px #FFF, 1605px 1520px #FFF, 403px 1602px #FFF, 913px 924px #FFF, 408px 1894px #FFF, 1041px 1916px #FFF, 1144px 1095px #FFF, 269px 1790px #FFF, 260px 807px #FFF, 1483px 227px #FFF, 1022px 480px #FFF, 1710px 1712px #FFF, 952px 231px #FFF, 973px 411px #FFF, 1318px 600px #FFF, 1556px 1689px #FFF, 1986px 1219px #FFF, 193px 188px #FFF, 1670px 1650px #FFF, 402px 165px #FFF, 500px 1627px #FFF, 327px 1144px #FFF, 1033px 537px #FFF, 1807px 156px #FFF, 717px 412px #FFF, 94px 1166px #FFF, 1536px 1716px #FFF, 33px 176px #FFF, 169px 1442px #FFF, 1504px 552px #FFF, 1487px 1057px #FFF, 436px 1875px #FFF, 1999px 1924px #FFF, 743px 661px #FFF, 1027px 730px #FFF, 84px 1325px #FFF, 1108px 816px #FFF, 1032px 1157px #FFF, 518px 716px #FFF, 1990px 529px #FFF, 270px 1776px #FFF, 895px 844px #FFF, 1918px 769px #FFF, 154px 1600px #FFF, 1829px 666px #FFF, 1937px 966px #FFF, 753px 157px #FFF, 956px 1364px #FFF, 1700px 1476px #FFF, 703px 1682px #FFF, 1570px 18px #FFF, 1134px 1840px #FFF, 427px 494px #FFF, 1744px 1293px #FFF, 1569px 598px #FFF, 547px 1218px #FFF, 20px 291px #FFF, 1907px 1169px #FFF, 930px 1101px #FFF, 1029px 526px #FFF, 16px 44px #FFF, 1462px 1984px #FFF, 62px 672px #FFF, 4px 816px #FFF, 720px 1881px #FFF, 88px 300px #FFF, 1863px 1553px #FFF, 45px 1902px #FFF, 8px 775px #FFF, 315px 765px #FFF, 1224px 1178px #FFF, 272px 1925px #FFF, 753px 1600px #FFF, 1653px 1384px #FFF, 267px 1416px #FFF, 255px 196px #FFF, 1520px 209px #FFF, 1441px 1128px #FFF, 1479px 777px #FFF, 1911px 124px #FFF, 1838px 1750px #FFF, 707px 1558px #FFF, 1565px 1477px #FFF, 92px 717px #FFF, 207px 1837px #FFF, 1531px 165px #FFF, 1923px 1538px #FFF, 715px 1590px #FFF, 419px 806px #FFF, 860px 793px #FFF, 1639px 365px #FFF, 78px 1562px #FFF, 1203px 1084px #FFF, 920px 1136px #FFF, 1431px 668px #FFF, 1237px 1836px #FFF, 583px 1797px #FFF, 1889px 108px #FFF, 844px 634px #FFF, 17px 1221px #FFF, 1957px 1684px #FFF, 293px 1225px #FFF, 1719px 1105px #FFF, 235px 1077px #FFF, 1721px 500px #FFF, 1965px 1572px #FFF, 840px 938px #FFF, 1365px 626px #FFF, 1622px 623px #FFF, 1296px 1008px #FFF, 1332px 753px #FFF, 530px 1947px #FFF, 955px 1836px #FFF, 1495px 1392px #FFF, 313px 577px #FFF, 975px 17px #FFF, 422px 75px #FFF, 1138px 1146px #FFF, 353px 1025px #FFF, 121px 1144px #FFF, 25px 709px #FFF, 1120px 1122px #FFF, 952px 307px #FFF, 407px 891px #FFF, 1045px 225px #FFF, 19px 1508px #FFF, 1584px 116px #FFF, 1041px 1838px #FFF, 1146px 1884px #FFF, 942px 967px #FFF, 115px 1700px #FFF, 640px 882px #FFF, 1048px 891px #FFF, 718px 1300px #FFF, 1294px 424px #FFF, 1382px 1857px #FFF, 38px 1098px #FFF, 1428px 1749px #FFF, 1622px 1828px #FFF, 601px 1076px #FFF, 887px 1358px #FFF, 1607px 594px #FFF, 1497px 509px #FFF, 1048px 704px #FFF, 75px 1482px #FFF, 281px 435px #FFF, 1291px 433px #FFF, 513px 1500px #FFF, 892px 966px #FFF, 307px 1615px #FFF, 220px 561px #FFF, 682px 1163px #FFF, 1867px 1457px #FFF, 243px 1922px #FFF, 1145px 1877px #FFF, 1619px 1486px #FFF, 248px 989px #FFF, 681px 1570px #FFF, 1416px 1691px #FFF, 540px 607px #FFF, 408px 825px #FFF, 430px 872px #FFF, 110px 1766px #FFF, 1511px 78px #FFF, 407px 686px #FFF, 804px 1769px #FFF, 286px 1294px #FFF, 1410px 1353px #FFF, 1199px 1044px #FFF, 700px 1492px #FFF, 1567px 114px #FFF, 208px 103px #FFF, 1708px 1370px #FFF, 260px 1390px #FFF, 1218px 688px #FFF, 377px 34px #FFF
}

.button {
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#stars2:after,
#stars3:after,
#stars:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 2000px
}

#stars3,
#stars3:after {
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    background: 0 0;
    box-shadow: 1136px 1762px #FFF, 1971px 1721px #FFF, 913px 1385px #FFF, 1879px 1324px #FFF, 1812px 1682px #FFF, 1571px 1835px #FFF, 956px 1241px #FFF, 927px 389px #FFF, 1597px 556px #FFF, 1592px 246px #FFF, 1400px 1300px #FFF, 1781px 1250px #FFF, 1942px 745px #FFF, 927px 379px #FFF, 1881px 989px #FFF, 1387px 884px #FFF, 553px 1486px #FFF, 476px 1335px #FFF, 1492px 11px #FFF, 499px 870px #FFF, 541px 376px #FFF, 1629px 1718px #FFF, 656px 1255px #FFF, 1908px 1236px #FFF, 1709px 1568px #FFF, 396px 1890px #FFF, 1515px 357px #FFF, 1140px 82px #FFF, 330px 177px #FFF, 336px 1856px #FFF, 1589px 1944px #FFF, 1016px 786px #FFF, 520px 1237px #FFF, 977px 549px #FFF, 171px 130px #FFF, 305px 1006px #FFF, 661px 1778px #FFF, 74px 1455px #FFF, 578px 66px #FFF, 60px 126px #FFF, 1383px 412px #FFF, 1232px 713px #FFF, 1819px 1398px #FFF, 1849px 1755px #FFF, 1615px 1637px #FFF, 205px 349px #FFF, 1681px 1505px #FFF, 87px 1456px #FFF, 1248px 1795px #FFF, 169px 1670px #FFF, 748px 1370px #FFF, 1303px 868px #FFF, 287px 1752px #FFF, 810px 161px #FFF, 493px 608px #FFF, 422px 564px #FFF, 1752px 1575px #FFF, 1290px 404px #FFF, 704px 1243px #FFF, 753px 1876px #FFF, 148px 981px #FFF, 940px 478px #FFF, 1966px 1351px #FFF, 1081px 1979px #FFF, 339px 1059px #FFF, 426px 1257px #FFF, 971px 225px #FFF, 1140px 733px #FFF, 597px 734px #FFF, 1780px 1684px #FFF, 877px 247px #FFF, 1125px 1194px #FFF, 18px 1206px #FFF, 1788px 1032px #FFF, 1291px 11px #FFF, 1406px 221px #FFF, 964px 1727px #FFF, 142px 1875px #FFF, 435px 1581px #FFF, 979px 1271px #FFF, 802px 279px #FFF, 136px 50px #FFF, 796px 598px #FFF, 563px 1080px #FFF, 627px 209px #FFF, 1907px 645px #FFF, 1543px 884px #FFF, 1039px 720px #FFF, 1179px 1072px #FFF, 1612px 1733px #FFF, 334px 1498px #FFF, 1553px 1938px #FFF, 856px 1991px #FFF, 1588px 253px #FFF, 1430px 909px #FFF, 681px 819px #FFF, 221px 1384px #FFF, 539px 1019px #FFF, 842px 1506px #FFF, 45px 1240px #FFF
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #B0BEC5;
    display: table;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: Lato, sans-serif
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle
}

.content {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block
}

.title {
    font-size: 82px;
    margin-bottom: 40px
}

.small {
    font-size: 34px;
    margin-top: -30px
}

html {
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, #1b2735 0, #090a0f 100%)
}

html::after {
    content: "";
    opacity: .3;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-position: top -72px
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@keyframes animStar {
    from {
        transform: translateY(600px)
    }
    to {
        transform: translateY(-2000px)
    }
}

#stars {
    background: 0 0;
    animation: animStar 50s linear infinite
}

#stars:after {
    background: 0 0
}

#stars2 {
    background: 0 0;
    animation: animStar 100s linear infinite
}

#stars2:after {
    background: 0 0
}

#stars3 {
    animation: animStar 150s linear infinite
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="stars"></div>
<div id="stars2"></div>
<div id="stars3"></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<div class="title">Welcome <?= $_SESSION['account']['username']; ?> !</div>
<br>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<button class="button" href="https//google.com">Link Here</button>

</div>
</div>
    <?= $StingCMS->SuiviGoogle(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Your html::after is completely covering the page, any clicks are sent directly to that psuedo element. Try adding `z-index:-50` to the css to the `html::after` pseudo element.
2. The button element is not a link. Change the `<button>` element to a `<a>` element.
3. https//google.com is not a valid URL -- adding a semi-colon after https: should fix this issue.

Answer (score -2):

There are 2 problems in your code.
One is that you're trying to use a `<button>` tag, that doesnt support the href argument (but would be clickable if it weren't for the second problem) you want to switch this to a `<a>` tag

```
<a class="button" href="https//google.com">Link Here</a>
```

The second is the  `content: ""` in `html:after` which makes your link unclickable.

here is a fiddle i made for you: https://jsfiddle.net/c69ae5n8/